# Flutter JSON Array Parsing getting error : Exception: type '(dynamic) => xxx is not a subtype of type '(Map<String, dynamic>) => List<xxx>' of 'f'

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, jsonparser

Sorry if It's repeated the question but I didn't found a solution.

**Error:**

> Exception: type '(dynamic) => PostalModel' is not a subtype of type
> '(Map<String, dynamic>) => List' of 'f'

**What I have done:**

1. Calling API:

   ```
   Future<PostalModel> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
      final response =
       await client.get('https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/364710');

      // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
      return compute(parsePostalPincode, response.body);
   }
   ```
2. parsing JSON:

   ```
    // A function that converts a response body into a List.
    PostalModel parsePostalPincode(String responseBody) {
      print(responseBody);
      final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      print('Parsed : $parsed'); //Getting Log OUTPUT
      PostalModel postalModel = parsed.map<List<PostalModel>>((json) => PostalModel.fromJson(json));
      print('Postal Model : $postalModel'); //Getting Log OUTPUT
      return postalModel;
    }
   ```
3. Binding Data in body:

   ```
   body: FutureBuilder<PostalModel>(
     future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       print('snapshot $snapshot'); // Getting Error Here
       // "AsyncSnapshot<PostalModel>(ConnectionState.done, null, Exception: type '(dynamic) => PostalModel' is not a subtype of type '(Map<String, dynamic>) => List<PostalModel>' of 'f')"
       if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

       return snapshot.hasData
          ? PostOfficeList(postOfficeList: snapshot.data.postOffice)
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
     },
   ),
   ```

You can check JSON from API Link and I have created a Model class from [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).

Answer (score 0):

And finally, I got succeed with the following solution:

```
// A function that converts a response body into a List.
PostalModel parsePostalPincode(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  print('Parsed : $parsed[0]'); 
  PostalModel postalModel = PostalModel.fromJson(parsed[0]);
  print('Postal Model : $postalModel');
  return postalModel;
}
```

Flutter is so crazy for a newbie. :P